# Parse double quotes and single quotes in Json Parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ipad, encoding

I am parsing a JSON url. I am getting `\u00e2\u20ac\u0153` instead of single quotes and `\u00e2\u20ac\u009d` instead of double quotes. On my end i am doing `NSUTF8StringEncoding` but still not getting single and double quotes.

Here is the response in the web browser:

> {"status":"1","data":[{"id":"1345","title_en":"","content_en":"Mom
>   said, \u00e2\u20ac\u0153I love this one.\u00e2\u20ac\u009d\n\nJake
>   said, \u00e2\u20ac\u0153I don\u00e2\u20ac\u2122t get
>   it.\u00e2\u20ac\u009d\n","image":"1396","pos":"2","video_type":"0","video":"0","video_alt":"","sound_type":"1","sound":"1123","sound_alt":"","author":"","type":"0","book_id":"148","user_id":"24","title":"The
>   Art
>   Museum","author_url":"maureen-d-1","book_url":"the-art-museum","video_filename":"","sound_filename":"atmuseum2.m4a"}]}

Is it possible to parse above response using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` or something else. Or i need to get it done from php side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use NSJSONSerialization? In my app i do this:

```
NSError* localError;
id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                   error:&localError];
```

In "data" variable i have response from server. I receiving UTF-encoded text from server too (like  \u00e2\u20ac) but finally i get normal string. "jsonObjects" will contain data in native types:

```
    if ([jsonObjects isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSNumber* age = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"age"];
    //...etc
    }
```

Comment: I checked my app. There is no UTF encoding for quotes in answer from server. Single quotes looks like \". Double quotes: \"\". I tried to decode your JSON on json online decoders like this http://json.parser.online.fr/ And this encoding \u00e2\u20ac\u0153 seems to be broken. So i think the problem in server side encoding, not in your objective-c code. It's my opinion.